# Why no output on console on signal handling?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I was trying this program from Advance Programming in Unix Environment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

static void handler(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGUSR1)
        printf("handled user1 signal");
    else if(sig == SIGUSR2)
        printf("handles user2 signal");
    else
        printf("unkown signal");
}

int main(){

    if(signal(SIGUSR1, handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("can't handle signal SIGUSR1");
    if(signal(SIGUSR2, handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("can't handle signal SIGUSR2");
    for(;;)
        pause();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I compile the program with gcc and then run a.out as indicated in the book.

$./a.out&
[1]+ 1345

$ kill -USR1 1345

But there is no output printed. The program keeps running in backgound and I have to kill it.

Other things I have tried:

1. Tried handling SIGINT to see if running program in background is causing problems. Still no output.
2. Downloaded latest release of FreeBSD and tried the same program on it, but with same problem.
3. I put a printf statement before setting signal handler:

   ```
   int main(){
       printf("printf is working...");
       //exit(0);
       if(signal(SIGUSR1, handler) == SIG_ERR)
       ...
   ```

when exit() is commented, there is no output. When I uncomment it, the output is printed.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong in this?

PS: Don't suggest using sigaction(). I am learning Unix Programming, not building any practical application.

Comment: Suspect you need to flush standard output as it is buffered. However, there are limitations around what can be done in a signal handler (I'll try and locate the link that someone gave to me detailing this).

Comment: Here it is: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

Comment: The proper suggestion isn't `sigaction()`, but rather `signalfd` and `epoll` :-) *That* will make you get serious at Linux programming.

Comment: @hmjd - thanks for response. yes the output is buffered and putting newline character at the end of statements worked out

Comment: @KerrekSB - after signal() they are next :)

Comment: either call `fflush(0)` or add a `\n` at the end of your strings

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The output from `printf` is buffered. That means it's stored in memory until flushed to the output. The best way to flush text in `printf` is to end the text with a newline. You can also flush manually with the `fflush` function.

However, you should be cautioned that using output functions like `printf` and `fflush` is not considered safe in signal handlers.

Comment: yes i know, they are not reentrant functions. but, i am just using them for learning purpose.

Comment: Learning is the best time to learn not to use unsafe functions in a signal handler.  A list of safe functions is available at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html  Just use `write` instead of `printf/fflush`.