# Why signal handling is malfunctioning?

Tags: c, linux, bsd, signal-handling

I have a signal handling snippet but it is somehow malfunctioning on my Mac and virtual Linux box at [koding.com](http://www.koding.com) but on my office Linux PC it is working..Can someone please tell me why..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_isr(int n){
   printf("Hello World");
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

}


int main(){
   signal(SIGINT, my_isr);
   printf("pid = %d\n", getpid());
   while(1);

   return 0;
 }
```

When I am pressing Ctrl+C it is not printing `Hello World` on the first time but it is re-modifying the `SIGINT` signal action & hence it is exiting the program when I press Ctrl+C second time. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Using printf in a signal handler is *undefined behavior* in ISO C. But it is allowed to change a file scope variable of type sig_atomic_t in a signal handler. You should test this variable in your while loop.

Comment: `printf` is not re-entrant, since it holds a global resource stdout. in general, all functions reserve global states and fail to manipulate all involved ones atomically are not re-entrant.

Comment: @Jens: It's actually not undefined behaviour in general. The restriction is (very roughly) that you can't call any (unsafe) library functions from the signal handler *if they might be running* at the time the signal is delivered. So assuming the user only presses Ctrl+C after the `pid=<N>` message has been displayed, there is no UB.

Comment: @psmears: From the C11Draft 7.14.1.1/5: "*If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function, the
behavior is undefined [...] if the signal handler calls any function
in the standard library other than the `abort` function, the `_Exit` function, the
`quick_exit function` [...]*"

Comment: @alk: Right (and if you need to run on a non-POSIX C system you'll have to abide by that) but in general that restriction is relaxed by POSIX - see IEEE Std 1003.1-2013 Vol.2 Ch. 2.4: *"In the presence of signals, all functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2008(sic) shall behave as defined when called from or interrupted by a signal-catching function, with a single exception: when a signal interrupts an unsafe function and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined."* (`printf` is such an unsafe function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not allowed to call every function in a signal handler.

Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). **Only *async signal safe* functions can be called** (directly or indirectly) **from a signal handler**, and `printf` is not such a function. If you really want to reliably "print" something from inside a signal handler (which I don't recommend), you can only use the low-level [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall (it is async signal safe).

So you've got [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) explains why it is so **bad**.

The recommended way is to set a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag in your signal handler, and to test it *outside* of it (e.g. in your `while` loop...).
And you forgot to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html). You might be more lucky by ending your `printf` format string with `\n` since `stdout`  is line-buffered!

Of course, changing your `printf` inside your signal handler is still UB, even with a `\n`, but very often it would appear to work.

Here is a conforming version of your program....

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t got_signal;

void my_sigint_handler (int signum) {
  if (signum == SIGINT) // this is always true!
    got_signal = 1;
#define INTERRUPT_MESSAGE "Interrupted!\n"
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, INTERRUPT_MESSAGE, strlen(INTERRUPT_MESSAGE));
};

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  struct sigaction act_int;
  memset (&act_int, 0, sizeof(act_int));
  act_int.sa_handler = my_sigint_handler;
  if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act_int, NULL)) {
     perror("sigaction"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };
  printf ("start %s pid %d\n", argv[0], (int)getpid());
  while (!got_signal) {
  };
  printf ("ended %s after signal\n", argv[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

A useful (and permissible) trick could be to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) a single byte -inside your signal handler- on a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self (you set up that pipe using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) early at program initialization), and in your event loop [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) the read end of that pipe.

Comment: So if I need to print something in signal handler, what I should use? and How?

Comment: can you please post a snippet to show how to so that ??

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: Use might use the `write()` function (if available), as mentioned by Basile, but also straight forward by `write()`ing to Standard Output.

Answer (score 0):

printf is the culprit just use counter in handler and print outside handler its value it will work.

use sigaction instead of signal

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: using signal() is not recommended as it is not compitible with all versions of unix systems. every flavor implement its own version so avoid it. never use printf() in exception handlers and signal handlers

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Comment: this is simple explanation of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139609/why-no-output-on-console-on-signal-handling?rq=1

Comment: Your explanation of the issue's root-cause does not really exist.

Comment: trust on my answer your accepted answer is also true and more ellaborative follow that it will solve your problem :)